# Do...Until - Read-Host with ValidPattern

Tags: powershell

I wanted to create a read-host that checks for a specific date format. Furthermore, the goals was to check if the input of the user is correct, if not, then the prompt should pop up again.

As I am new to programming I found this code, that seemed to fit. Still I am struggling with the part of "until"

```
    do
{
    try {
    [ValidatePattern("yyyyMMdd")]$Date = Read-Host -Prompt "Please input a valid date in format YYYYMMDD!"
    } catch {}
} until ($?)
```

Tbh, I do not know what ($?) should do...I know that until needs to compare the user input with the validpattern "yyyyMMdd", but I do not know how to do that.
I tried a few combinations but unsuccessfull...

Comment: [1] the ValidatePattern attribute expects a _regex pattern_ ... and your pattern is not valid. [*grin*] [2] the more common method to use is `[datetime]::ParseExact()`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey FWIW the pattern is a _valid regex pattern_ - it'll match `"yyyyMMdd"`,`"YYYYmmDD"` and any other mix-cased permutation of itself you can think of :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - tthhhhbbbpppttt!!!! i meant that it aint valid for matching a date. [*grin*] should i remove that comment and add back one that is more explicit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[ValidatePattern()]` attribute is not a good fit for your validation routine.

It takes a regular expression pattern as its argument, and regular expressions only concerns itself with *text* - it doesn't know anything about date formatting, and `yyyyMMdd` has no special meaning to the regex engine - you're basically asking powershell to validate that the input was *the literal value "yyyyMMdd"*.

You might want to use [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__) for this instead:

```
$Date = [datetime]::MinValue
do
{
  $DateStringInput = Read-Host -Prompt "Please input a valid date in format YYYYMMDD!"
} until ([datetime]::TryParseExact($DateStringInput.Trim(), 'yyyyMMdd', $null, 'None', [ref]$Date))
```

Inside the loop we just prompt the user for the input string, and then in the `until` condition statement we ask `DateTime.TryParseExact()` to parse the input given the specified format and assign it to the `$Date` variable, ensuring we loop again if it fails.

Comment: Just in case someone wants to use the code from @MathiasR.Jessen, I would add the following: `$DateStringInput = (Read-Host -Prompt "Please input a valid date in format YYYYMMDD!").Trim()` In case the user accidentally puts in any spaces before or after the input, they ll be ignored.